# How to make header div size fixed and body as scrollable?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-4

```
Here is the sample code for that: its just a sample:
<div class="main">
<div class="header">
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
Header<br>
</div>
<div class="footer">
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
Footer<br>
</div>
</div>

css:
.header{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footer{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.main{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0s4xmc0/54524/)
        I have one scenario where I dont have idea about my div size of 
        parent , which is written in iframe and I am inserting angular 
        template in the iframe but I am able to fixed the header but i 
        cant make it scrollable .  I can make it scrollable by providing 
        the height in div which i cant do since i

Comment: Hi Pete , sorry for having not a correct format , not adapted with stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Used Infinite Scroll via NPM : - **InfiniteScrollModule**

import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';

and also used CSS for fixed body.

like this :-

.modal{display: block !important; }

.modal-header .close{margin-top:0px;}

.modal-dialog{ overflow-y: initial !important}

.modal-body{  height: 20rem;  overflow-y: auto;}